# Microsoft Word: How can I insert vertical bars in the margin when a particular Style occurs?

Tags: ms-word

While using Microsoft Word, I'd like to insert a vertical bar next to any occurrences of text with a particular style (eg. "Style X"). This would be a similar effect to the vertical bars inserted with edited text in Track Changes mode.

My thoughts/attempts so far:

- I can create a Paragraph Style that has a border setting. Unfortunately, for a single sentence of Style X within a paragraph, I have to insert Style Separators (not a show-stopper) and the border line is removed (is a show-stopper). (See first example in image)
- I can create a Character Style with a border around only the text (what I'm using now), but this is a little too much/distracting. (See second example in image)
- I can create a Linked Style with a border, but this also removes the border when the text is embedded within a larger paragraph of a different style. (See third example in image)

[Three failed attempts and a fourth (doctored) desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crxpi.png)

I figure I'm probably asking too much of Word, but I have too many colleagues that cannot use tex. Does anybody know of a way to achieve the desired effect in an efficient manner? (Also let me know if this should be on Super User.)